# Icons used via fonts (hosted locally) won't display in Firefox

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, firefox, fonts

I'm locally hosting my icons in the form of fonts, using @font-face in font.css.sass file, and referencing that in a generic style.css.scss file. (I've essentially copy-pasted-modified from a site for generating social media icons, [PerfectIcons.com](http://www.perfecticons.com). The icons appear exactly as expected in all browsers except Firefox. Even so, Firefox receives and renders my other @font-face fonts with no issue.

Perhaps the problem is related to the svg file that is used for the social icons, and the way Firefox handles that?

NB. the asset_url below is something for Rails 4 and Heroku.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'si';
  src:    asset_url('socicon.eot');
  src:    asset_url('socicon.eot?#iefix') format(embedded-opentype),
          asset_url('socicon.woff') format(woff),
          asset_url('socicon.ttf') format(truetype),
          asset_url('socicon.svg') format(svg);
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'si';
    src: asset_url('socicon.svg') format(svg);
  }
}
```

And then the style.css.scss:

```
.soc
  overflow: hidden
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  list-style: none
  text-align: right
  margin-right: 100px

 .soc li
   display: inline-block
   *display: inline
   zoom: 1

.soc li a
  font-family: si !important
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box
  -o-box-sizing: border-box
  box-sizing: border-box
  text-decoration: none
  text-align: center
  display: block
  position: relative
  z-index: 1
  width: 35px
  height: 35px
  line-height: 35px
  font-size: 19px
  @include border-radius(50px)
  color: #c9c8c8
  background-color: #383838
  opacity: .8

.soc-icon-last
  margin: 0 !important

.soc-twitter:before
  content: 'a'

.soc-facebook:before
  content: 'b'

.soc-google:before
  content: 'c'
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? This will help in providing an answer.

Comment: I can see the social icons on my Firefox.

Comment: I tried it without Rails, just a html file in the browser. Same thing... it worked for Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. Just in case, for FF it still shows the letters/numbers with colors, but not the actual icons.

Comment: When I go to the URL in Firefox I can see the actual icons. Are you using the most recent Firefox version? Try clearing your cache as well. It may have cached a bad file.

Comment: I'm using FF 30. Cleared cache... but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56237/discussion-between-zachzurn-and-rfish26535).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifiers need to be in quotes as shown below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'si';
  src:    asset_url('socicon.eot');
  src:    asset_url('socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          asset_url('socicon.woff') format('woff'),
          asset_url('socicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
          asset_url('socicon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: It did... the difference is the quotations around the format declaration. Seemed to be the issue with FF.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this code with your code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'si';
  src:    url('<%= asset_path('socicon.eot') %>');
  src:    url('<%= asset_path('socicon.eot) + '?#iefix' %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('<%= asset_path('socicon.woff') %>') format('woff'),
          url('<%= asset_path('socicon.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
          url('<%= asset_path('socicon.svg') %>') format('svg');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Change css file extention to **.css.scss.erb**